# Unresponsive script issue on angular 4 app load

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I Have build an app in angular 4 using angular cli v 1.1.1, and its working properly excepts 1 issue that is unresponsive script on app load. when I click continue it loads fully and works fine. following is the error I got

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:198363"

I have updates all the modules to latest but its still showing the same error and dont how to debug it now. can anyone help on this ?

Comment: vendor.bundle.js contain your imported modules in app.module.ts so check if any one of your module doing infinite loop. are you running ng serve or AOT build

Comment: I am running npm start, ng server. it happens with AOT build too